# Publish key value with redis/ vue

Tags: javascript, database, vue.js, redis, localhost

I have a set of keys

```
key1, value1
key2, value2
```

The values get updated every few seconds.

My ultimate goal is to have a table on localhost which displays the key-values.

I would be happy with just finding a way to publish the values on localhost.

This is what I have as of now:

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
        message : "Here I can write straight to localhost"
    }
  },
  created() {
    try {
        const ws = new WebSocket( "ws://localhost:3000") ;
        ws.onmessage = ({data}) => {
            this.message = data;    
            console.log( data );
        }   
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
  },  
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
```

Comment: Needs more clarification.

Comment: the key and the key_value are stored with Redis. A script is generating/ updating the values every couple seconds.
I know I can publish messages to my localhost, but I dont know how I can send the key-values

Comment: You showed us you frontend code (vue app) but have not published any of your backend or what your "localhost" definition is. " I can publish messages to my localhost" your localhost what?! Or what/how do you want to publish anything to this "mysterious" localhost thing.

Comment: In the backend I have a very simple redisClient.set("keyname", keyvalue) command

Answer (score 0):

Since this is getting some traffic I thought I'd post my solution:
The answer is to not store the data as key-value pairs but to use the pub/sub function of Redis.